# Appcompat-v7 conflict in android

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-library

I ran into a nasty problem. In my project I have a library (.aar) file which is including an appcompat-v7 compatibility library. Now in my project I also have another appcompat-v7 under the dependency section of gradle.build (app) file..

The problem is when I run the Application it throws an exception saying

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$anim;
```

Here is my application gradle.build (app) file relevant part (I think so)

```
repositories {
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile(name: 'conversityChat-debug', ext: 'aar') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v7'
    }
}
```

And here is my library gradle.build(app) file relevant part (I think so)

```
dependencies {
compile project(':androidwebsocketsmaster')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.4.jar')
}
```

I'm using android studio.. I know this question has been asked before, and I've tried out all possible solutions suggested over there. Sadly, None of them helped... Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code to your gradle :

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Add below dependency and add HttpCore and HttpClient also.

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

For more information check below link :

https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
```

from your outer level build.gradle file (the top one) you only need it in your project level build.gradle file.

Comment: I don't have that in my project level build.gradle file.. The top one is the application build.gradle (app) file and the bottom one is the custom library build.gradle file... Could you be more specific please?

Comment: You have two build.gradle files, one which is in your app directory and one which is in the root of your project. You want to be putting the appcompat dependency in the app one not the root one. The error is saying that you're specifying it twice.