# android jar file content support-v7

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I'm using a library by JAR file in android studio, the problem is the library-jar file  already has support-v7 , My project also need add support-7 , therefor I get error : `Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$anim;`
Any help ?

Comment: can you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123181/appcompat-v7-conflict-in-android) , [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102598/android-studio-unexpected-top-level-exception) , [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059719/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define) which may helps to solving your problem.

Comment: Remove the support-v7.jar

Answer (score 0):

Please try this gradle code into your `gradle` file.

```
android {
dexOptions {
preDexLibraries = false
}
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but no luck :
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$anim;

Comment: can you post your `gradle` for more idea?

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile files('libs/libreoffice.jar')
}
here is my dependencies

Comment: just make comment `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'` --> rebuild

Comment: as per your error suggest `appcompat-v7` already contain in _libreoffice.jar_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92679/discussion-between-pranay-and-linh-nguyen).